# list-style-type:none & list-style:none not working

Tags: html, css, list

I'm having trouble removing list bullets - I've tried both `list-style-type:none` & `list-style:none`, both inline and in the CSS file. Also tried adding `!important` all to no avail. Here's what I've got:

```
<ul id="work">
    <li><img src="#" /><p>SERVICE 1</p></li>
    <li><img src="#" /><p>SERVICE 2</p></li>
    <li><img src="#" /><p>SERVICE 3</p></li>
</ul>



#work ul {
   list-style-type: none;
}

#work li {
   list-style-type: none;
   clear: both;
}

#work li img {
   float: left;
   padding-right: 25px;
   margin-bottom: 25px;
}

#work li p {
   height:240px;
}
```

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't duplicate your issue; it's removing the bullets. You need to provide more info so we can duplicate your issue.

Comment: The code necessary to duplicate your issue must be included in the question itself. People need to be able to see the problem later, after it's no longer present on your site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your selector doesn’t match anything – `#work ul` would select any UL elements *inside* the element that has the id `work`.

If you want to select the HTML element `<ul id="work">`, then use `ul#work`, or just `#work` (when ids are involved, it is in most cases not necessary to be any more specific.)

---

Edit:
So, after you’ve shown the link to your page, it becomes clear that your issue is not with `list-style` at all – that works fine, your LI do not have a list style.

But what they do have, is a pseudo element – and *that* is what creates the small dark-pink dot.

http://answersfornewactors.com/wp-content/themes/gardeniablog/style.css, line #2483:

```
.post_content ul > li:before {
    font-family: "fontello";
    content: '\e8e4';
    font-size: 0.5em;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-indent: -2em;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately changing to `ul#work` or `#work` did not work for me.

Comment: Well as has already been said in comments, it seems your code as shown does not replicate the issue. So please create a [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for the edited response - you pointed me in the right direction. I added `.post_content ul > li:before { display:none }` to achieve my desired results.